# Table with unneeded whitespace in first column with blank first two rows

Tags: tables

Anyone able to help me remove the extra width from the first column, aiming for soething like the second image (taken from word) - Code as follows, producing image 1 below.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Experiment 2} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Experiment 4} \\ \cline{2-9} 
& 3.5°   & 7°     & 10.5°  & 14°   & 0.875°  & 1.75°  & 3.5°  & 10.5° \\ \hline
Size              & 4.00   & 5.77   & 7.54   & 9.32  & 1.34    & 1.56   & 2.00  & 3.77  \\
Scale Factor      & 1.00   & 1.44   & 1.89   & 2.33  & 0.33    & 0.39   & 0.50  & 0.94  \\ \hline
SpatialFrequency & 1.00   & 0.69   & 0.53   & 0.43  & 1.50    & 1.28   & 1.00  & 0.53  \\
Scale Factor      & 1.00   & 0.69   & 0.53   & 0.43  & 1.50    & 1.28   & 1.00  & 0.53  \\ \hline
\stoptable{\textit{Note: Scale factors are relative to the size and spatial frequency of the 3.5° condition in Experiment 2.}}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Sizes, spatial frequencies, and their associated scale factors for the four eccentricity conditions in Experiments 2 and 4.}
\label{tab2_9}
\end{table}
```

[image: table with whitespace]

[image: image without whitespace]

Comment: `\stoptable` is not a standard command, which gives me an error, and TeX responds by putting the entire Note into the first column.  Why not put the note into the caption?  Or what package should be defining `\stoptable`?

Comment: also, never use `\resizebox` on tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}l*{8}{X[c]}@{}}%
[tabularnote =  \itshape Scale factors are relative to the size and 
     spatial frequency of the 3.5° condition in Experiment 2. ]
    \toprule
    \RowStyle[bold]{}
    & \Block{1-4}{Experiment 2} & & & & \Block{1-4}{Experiment 4} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5} 
    \cmidrule(l){6-9}
        & 3.5°     & 7°       & 10.5°    & 14°
        & 0.875°   & 1.75°    & 3.5°     & 10.5° \\
    \midrule
    Size    & 4.00  & 5.77  & 7.54  & 9.32  & 1.34  & 1.56  & 2.00  & 3.77  \\
    Scale Factor      
            & 1.00  & 1.44  & 1.89  & 2.33  & 0.33  & 0.39  & 0.50  & 0.94  \\  \midrule
    Spatial Frequency 
            & 1.00  & 0.69  & 0.53  & 0.43  & 1.50  & 1.28  & 1.00  & 0.53  \\
    Scale Factor      
        & 1.00  & 0.69  & 0.53  & 0.43  & 1.50  & 1.28  & 1.00  & 0.53  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular} 

\caption{Sizes, spatial frequencies, and their associated scale factors for the four eccentricity conditions in Experiments 2 and 4.}
\label{tab2_9}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is use of `tabularray` package. Its `talltblr` environment offer function `remark` for writing remarks below table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{} % <---
\SetTblrStyle{remark}{\small\itshape}
\begin{talltblr}[
remark{Note} = {Scale factors are relative to the size and spatial frequency of the \ang{3.5} condition in Experiment 2.}
                ]{colsep=2pt,
                  colspec = {@{} l*{8}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2{*}}]}
                            @{}   },
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries}                  
                }
    \toprule
    &\SetCell[c=4]{c}   {{{Experiment 2}}}
        &       &       &       &\SetCell[c=4]{c}   {{{Experiment 4}}}       
                                        &       &       &       \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-5} 
    \cmidrule[l]{6-9}
        & \ang{3.5}     & \ang{7}       & \ang{10.5}    & \ang{14}   
        & \ang{0.875}   & \ang{1.75}    & \ang{3.5}     & \ang{10.5} \\
    \midrule
Size    & 4.00  & 5.77  & 7.54  & 9.32  & 1.34  & 1.56  & 2.00  & 3.77  \\
Scale Factor      
        & 1.00  & 1.44  & 1.89  & 2.33  & 0.33  & 0.39  & 0.50  & 0.94  \\  \midrule[dashed]
Spatial Frequency 
        & 1.00  & 0.69  & 0.53  & 0.43  & 1.50  & 1.28  & 1.00  & 0.53  \\
Scale Factor      
        & 1.00  & 0.69  & 0.53  & 0.43  & 1.50  & 1.28  & 1.00  & 0.53  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr} 

\caption{Sizes, spatial frequencies, and their associated scale factors for the four eccentricity conditions in Experiments 2 and 4.}
\label{tab2_9}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `\stoptable` directive -- did you maybe copy it from a ConTeXt-based example? -- doesn't appear to be defined. Hence, LaTeX just dumps the directive's argument in what happens to be the first column. As others have already pointed out, just place the legend *below* the main tabular material.

I would further like to strongly recommend that you not apply the `\resizebox` sledgehammer to the table and, instead, employ a `tabularx` environment and apply the `X` column type to the first column. Replacing `\hline` and `\cline` with the macros of the `booktabs` package would also be a nice touch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X *{8}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Experiment 2} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Experiment 4} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
                  & 3.5°  & 7°   & 10.5° & 14°  & 0.875°& 1.75°& 3.5° & 10.5° \\ 
\midrule
Size              & 4.00  & 5.77 & 7.54  & 9.32 & 1.34  & 1.56 & 2.00 & 3.77  \\
Scale Factor      & 1.00  & 1.44 & 1.89  & 2.33 & 0.33  & 0.39 & 0.50 & 0.94  \\ 
\addlinespace
Spatial Frequency & 1.00  & 0.69 & 0.53  & 0.43 & 1.50  & 1.28 & 1.00 & 0.53  \\
Scale Factor      & 1.00  & 0.69 & 0.53  & 0.43 & 1.50  & 1.28 & 1.00 & 0.53  \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\small\textit{Note}:
    Scale factors are relative to the size and spatial frequency 
    of the 3.5° condition in Experiment 2.}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Sizes, spatial frequencies, and associated scale factors for the four eccentricity conditions in Experiments 2 and 4.}
\label{tab2_9}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```